# Mvc 3 outputcache varyByCustom extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, outputcache

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 120, VaryByCustom = "siteId")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     if(ConfigHelper.SiteId == 1)
        //massive logic here;
     else if(ConfigHelper.SiteId == 2)
        //massive logic here; 
     else if(ConfigHelper.SiteId == 3)
        //massive logic here; 
     return View(model);
}


 // from Config helper
 public static int SiteId
 {
      get { return GetAppSettingsValue<int>("SiteId", 0); }
 }
```

Index method invoke when I type localhost. It is homepage.
Can anyone know how to get varyByCustom from config setting value ?